# Confusion in showing that the graph of a smooth function is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Tu's book *An Introduction to Manifolds* (second edition). Specifically, Example $5.14$ in Section $5.4$ which states that

> For a subset of $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, the graph of $f$ is defined to be the subset
> $$\Gamma(f)=\{(x,f(x))\in A\times\mathbb{R}^m\}$$
> If $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, then the two maps
> $$\phi:\Gamma(f)\rightarrow U,\ (x,f(x))\mapsto x,\ 
> (\textbf{1},f):U\rightarrow\Gamma(f),\ x\mapsto (x,f(x))$$
> are continuous and inverse to each other, and so are homeomorphism.

My questions are the following:

1. How can $f$ map points from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and at the same time from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$?
2. What exactly is the notation $(\textbf{1},f):U\rightarrow\Gamma(f)$? I haven't seen anything like that before...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the first sentence, Tu is defining the graph $\Gamma(f)$ of a function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In the second sentence, Tu is applying that definition to a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $U$ is open and claiming that $\Gamma(f)$ is homeomorphic to $U$. (Note, there is a typo in the book. Tu writes $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ when it should be $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$, see the discussion in the comments below.)
2. Here Tu is using ${\bf 1}$ to denote the identity function ${\bf 1} : U \to U$, so ${\bf 1}(x) = x$. So $({\bf 1}, f) : U \to U\times\mathbb{R}^n$ with $({\bf 1}, f)(x) = ({\bf 1}(x), f(x)) = (x, f(x))$ which actually lies in $\Gamma(f)$, the graph of $f$, so we can instead regard $({\bf 1}, f)$ as a map $U \to \Gamma(f)$.

Comment: Hi @Michael Albanese and thanks for your answer! I am unsure if I understand your reply to (1), though? Tu clearly states that $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it a typo and we should only have only $n$ or $m$??

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when reading your question. Yes, it is a typo. The next sentence in the book is "The graph $\Gamma(f)$ of a $C^{\infty}$ function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ has an atlas with a single chart $(\Gamma(f), \varphi)$, and is
therefore a $C^{\infty}$ manifold." Also see Figure $5.6$.

Comment: So, there is no chance for $f$ to send points from open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: I think the typo is this: $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ should be $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, right?

Comment: In the second sentence, Tu should have written: "If $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^{\color{red}{m}}$".

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I get it now